# How to treat a file in a distributed client / server application for file sharing

Tags: c

Im trying to make a distributed client / server application for file sharing. I firstly made a LIST_FILES function which reads and prints all the files of your directory, but Im having trouble deleting and renaming .txt files. If I manually use the name of the .txt in the functions, it works for both, but I dont know how to properly read from the server which file I want to use. Im using cygwin, C code and Windows.

Example: ./server.exe --> ./client.exe 127.0.0.1 DELETE_FILE test.txt or MOVE_FILE test.txt newtest.txt

SERVER

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>    // Close sockets
#include <dirent.h>

#define MAXDATASIZE 5000
#define _BUFFER_SIZE 2000
#define ECHO_PORT 5675
#define FAIL "SEND_FAILED"

long fileSize(const char fileNom[]);
int getFiles(char *cadena, int longitud);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *namefile;
    int i, del, ren, leng, length2, length3;

    int socket_desc, accepted_socket, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr; // Direccion del servidor
    char down[_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char response[_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char reply[_BUFFER_SIZE] = "SUCCESS";
    char reply2[_BUFFER_SIZE] = "ERROR";
    char buffer[_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char buffer2[_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char buffer3[_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char ack[_BUFFER_SIZE] = "ACK";

    printf("Initializing echo server\n");

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Sock stream --> SOCKET TCP
    if (socket_desc < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    char *address = "0.0.0.0"; // Accept connections from the whole Internet
    if (argc > 1)
        address = argv[1];
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(ECHO_PORT);

    bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    listen(socket_desc, 10);

    int exit = 0;

    while (!exit)
    {
        printf("Echo server. Waiting for incoming connections from clients.\n");
        accepted_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL);
        printf("Accepted a connection from client\n");

        // First wait for the command of the client
        ssize_t len = recv(accepted_socket, buffer, _BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
        // If the client sends two or more arguments, the second is the file's name
        

        if (len < 0)
        {
            printf("recv failed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            char fileName[_BUFFER_SIZE];
            char command[_BUFFER_SIZE];
            char command2[_BUFFER_SIZE];
            printf("Received command from client: %s\n", buffer); // TODO: If the message is too long --> may print garbage

            /*
            We check the length of buffer2 and buffer3, if the length is 
            >= 1, it means that the client sent those
            */

            length2 = strlen(buffer2);
            if (length2 >= 1)
                printf("Received file's name from client: %s\n", buffer2);

            length3 = strlen(buffer3);
            if (length3 >= 1)
                printf("Received new file's name from client: %s\n", buffer3);

            if (strcmp(buffer, "LIST_FILES") == 0)
            {
               printf("Received LIST_FILES command --> stopping server\n");
                getFiles(buffer, _BUFFER_SIZE);

                printf("Directory list: \n %s", buffer);

                len = strlen(buffer);
                if (send(accepted_socket, buffer, len, 0) < 0)
                {
                    printf("Send failed\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            else if (strcmp(buffer, "DOWNLOAD_FILE") == 0)
            {
                i = 10;
                long length = 0;
                length = fileSize(buffer2);
                printf("Received DOWNLOAD_FILE command %s, size: %ld \n", buffer2, length);
                if (length >= 0)
                {
                    //We enter in the If command just in case the size of the file is positive
                    sprintf(down, "%ld", length);
                    send(accepted_socket, down, _BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
                    recv(accepted_socket, ack, _BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
                    if (strcmp(ack, "ACK") == 0) //Checking the ACK message from the client
                    {
                        printf("ACK RECEIVED \n");
                        /* Open the file that we wish to transfer */
                        FILE *fp = fopen(buffer2, "rb");
                        if (fp == NULL)
                        {
                            printf("Error opening the file");
                            return 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            while (1)
                            {
                                //Reading and sending the file the client wants to download
                                unsigned char buff[_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
                                int nread = fread(buff, 1, _BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
                                printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);

                                if (nread > 0)
                                {
                                    printf("Sending \n");
                                    write(accepted_socket, buff, nread);
                                }

                                if (nread < _BUFFER_SIZE)
                                {
                                    if (feof(fp))
                                        printf("\nEnd of file\n");
                                    if (ferror(fp))
                                        printf("\nError reading\n");
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(buffer, reply2); //If ack doesn't is received, we send ERROR
                    printf("Error: unable to download the file\n");
                    send(accepted_socket, reply2, len, 0);
                }
            }

            else if (strcmp(buffer, "DELETE_FILE") == 0)
            {
                
                del = remove(buffer2); 

                if (del == 0)
                {
                    strcpy(buffer, reply);
                    printf("File deleted sucessfully\n");
                    send(accepted_socket, reply, len, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(buffer, reply2);
                    printf("Error: unable to delete the file\n");
                    send(accepted_socket, reply2, len, 0);
                }
            }

            else if (strcmp(buffer, "MOVE_FILE") == 0)
            {
                ren = rename("prueba.txt", "nuevaprueba.txt");

                if (ren == 0)
                {
                    strcpy(buffer, reply);
                    printf("File renamed successfully\n");
                    send(accepted_socket, reply, len, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    strcpy(buffer, reply2);
                    printf("Error: unable to rename the file\n");
                    send(accepted_socket, reply2, len, 0);
                }
            }

            close(accepted_socket);
            printf("Accepted connection closed.\n");
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    printf("Closing binded socket\n");
    close(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}

int getFiles(char *cadena, int longitud)
{

    int cont = 0;

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            cont += sprintf(cadena + cont, "%s\n", dir->d_name); // ¿Cuántos caracteres escribe la función? Contador, salir
        }

        closedir(d);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return cont;
}

long fileSize(const char fileNom[])
{
    long size = -1;

    FILE *fich;

    fich = fopen(fileNom, "rb");
    if (fich != NULL)
    {
        fseek(fich, 0L, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(fich);
        fclose(fich);
    }
    return size;
}
```

CLIENT

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ECHO_PORT 5675
#define _BUFFER_SIZE 20000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int len = 0, len2 = 0, bytesReceived = 0;
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char received[_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *message, server_reply[_BUFFER_SIZE], server_status[_BUFFER_SIZE], file_size[_BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *newNameOfFile = "";
    char *nameOfFile = "";
    char *comp;
    char *ack = "ACK";

    printf("Initializing socket\n");

    //Create socket
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    char *address = "127.0.0.1";
    if (argc > 1)
        address = argv[1]; // Si existe, el primer argumento es la IP
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(ECHO_PORT);

    printf("Trying to connect to address: %s\n", address);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Connect error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connected Successfully\n");

    //Send some data
    message = "ECHO";
    if (argc > 2)
        message = argv[2]; // If exists, the second argument is the message

    if (send(socket_desc, message, strlen(message) + 1, 0) < 0) // Importante el +1 para enviar el finalizador de cadena!!
    {
        printf("Send failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Message sent: %s\n", message);

    //Send the file we want to
    if (argc > 3)
        nameOfFile = argv[3]; // If exists, the third argument is the file name

    if (send(socket_desc, nameOfFile, strlen(nameOfFile) + 1, 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("Send failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //We check if NameOfFile's size is >= 1
    len = strlen(nameOfFile);
    if (len >= 1)
        printf("File name sent: %s\n", nameOfFile);

    //Send the new file's name
    if (argc > 4)
        newNameOfFile = argv[4]; // If exists, the fourth argument is the new file's name

    //Sending data to the server
    if (send(socket_desc, newNameOfFile, strlen(newNameOfFile) + 1, 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("Send failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //We check if newNameOfFile's size is >= 1
    len2 = strlen(newNameOfFile);
    if (len2 >= 1)
        printf("New file's name sent: %s\n", newNameOfFile);

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if (recv(socket_desc, server_status, _BUFFER_SIZE, 0) >= 1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", server_status);
    }
    //We change the type of the data
    long size = strtol(server_status, &comp, 10);

    if (size >= 1)
    {
        send(socket_desc, ack, _BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    } 

    /*If our order is DOWNLOAD_FILE, its create the file
     where we are storing the data*/
    if ((strcmp(message, "DOWNLOAD_FILE") == 0) && size >= 1)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(nameOfFile, "wb");
        if (NULL == fp)
        {
            printf("Error opening file");
            return 1;
        }

        /* Receive data in chunks of 2000 bytes */
        while ((bytesReceived = read(socket_desc, received, _BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received %d\n", bytesReceived);
            fwrite(received, 1, bytesReceived, fp);
            
        }
        

        if (bytesReceived < 0)
        {
            printf("\n Read Error \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("SUCCESS");
        }
    }
        //Help Command, general and particullary for each command
         if (strcmp(message, "HELP") == 0)
            {
                printf("List of available commands: \n-LIST_FILES\n-DOWNLOAD_FILE <filename>\n-DELETE_FILE <filename>\n-MOVE_FILE <old_filename> <new_filename>\n \n \n For more help, type 'HELP_command'\n");
            }
            else if (strcmp(message, "HELP_LIST_FILES") == 0)
            {
                printf("Command: LIST_FILES \n");
                printf("-Shows every existing file in the folder. \n");
            }

            else if (strcmp(message, "HELP_DOWNLOAD_FILE") == 0)
            {
                printf("Command: DOWNLOAD_FILES <filename> \n");
                printf("-Downloads the requested file. \n");
            }

            else if (strcmp(message, "HELP_DELETE_FILE") == 0)
            {
                printf("Command: DELETE_FILE <filename> \n");
                printf("-Deletes the requested file. \n");
            }
            else if (strcmp(message, "HELP_MOVE_FILE") == 0)
            {
                printf("Command: MOVE_FILE <old_filename> <new_filename> \n");
                printf("-Renames the old_filename for the new_filename. \n");
            }

    close(socket_desc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what _"but If I try to read the name first, store it, and then treat It as I want, then it doesnt work"_ means exactly.  Please rephrase to add clarity to what you mean by doesn't work.  What does it not do, or do that is not satisfactory to you?

Comment: Hello, I dont know how to read the .txt and store it when I execute the ./client.exe 127.0.0.1 DELETE_FILE test.txt

In my code, when I put manually the .txt that i want to delete, it works, but I dont know how to properly read from  the server which file I want to use.